# If i disable iCloud from developer account then it will let me transfer my app to other account?

Tags: ios, app-transfer

i have uploaded my app to appstore with `iCloud` is enabled in app ID.

Now i want to transfer my app to other account but it shows error `"You can only transfer apps that aren’t iCloud enabled."`

So, if i uncheck `iCloud` option from App id then i will be able to transfer app or not?Is there need to upload app again after disabling `iCloud` then transfer is possible?

Comment: You can try, but I suspect that you won't be able to upload a new version that doesn't have the iCloud entitlement since your current version does.

Comment: @Paulw11 Oh, i can't try because my app started gaining users day by day and i can't take this risk.

Comment: You can try because I don't think you will be even able to upload a binary without iCloud, let alone release it.